# asking the user to input ints and then counting them

Tags: java, count, do-while

I need to write a code that takes the users input of numbers and adds them, displays the amount of positives, negatives, zeroes, and the count of the amount of numbers inputted once the user enters the letter 'e'. Im not sure if what i have so far is the correct path (it doesn't compile yet) but this is what i have so far:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int negative = 0;
        int positive = 0;
        int zeroes = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        do{
        System.out.print("Enter a float or 'e' to exit");
     int num = input.nextInt();

            if(num  < 0){
            sum += num;
            count++;
            negative++;
            }
            if (num > 0){
                sum += num;
                count++;
                positive++;
            }
            if (num == 0){
                sum += num;
                count++;
                zeroes++;

                if (num = e){
                    System.out.print(sum + count + zeroes + positive + negative);
                }

            }
    } while(true);  
    }
```

}

Comment: `if(num  < 0);{` remove the `;`. And `if (num = e){` should be with `==`. But however... What is your question?

Comment: the issue i am having is the fact i cant convert an int to string so i dont know what to put in place of  (num = e)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Please note comments where I've tried to improve:

```
      do{
        System.out.print("Enter a float or 'e' to exit");
        String entered = input.nextLine();
        if("e".equals(entered)){
            //print stuff
            break;
        }else{
            int num;
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(entered);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Not a number nor e");
                continue; // re-do the loop
            }
            if(num  < 0){//; ends the line, not to be used after if condition
                sum += num;
                count++;
                negative++;
            }else if (num > 0){ // num bcan be >0 only if its not <0, so use else
                sum += num;
                count++;
                positive++;
            }else{//similar to comment above
                sum += num;
                count++;
                zeroes++;
            }

        }
    } while(true);
```

Comment: I think that the `//print stuff` should be `break` because this causes an infinite loop

Comment: Also, `if (num == 0) { sum += num }` seems unnecessary.

Comment: And `count++` can be moved out to the very end (or beginning) of the `else` :)